# Connection 3G in Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 3g, aquaris

I have the Ubuntu Edition Aquaris Terminal E5. The phone works great for calls and text messages, but connecting to mobile data and and navigating the internet it takes a long time to load a page.

I use the company Iusacell in Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

Lusacell might be using WCDMA technology for the data network and I did not find a WCDMA setting in Ubuntu-touch. My earlier Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 (android) had that setting and the data network was fast. When I used the same SIM card in BQ Auaris E5, the speed dropped. However I don't have any problem with a GSM data network. It works fine in Ubuntu touch.

Comment: And you could do? Wait for the update?
Why seriously my data connection is very slow

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My email server had some issues. I started using the GSM network after I switched to Ubuntu. Having WCDMA inconvenience is a small issue compared to the huge advantage of a open source operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The E5 Ubuntu Edition is not compatible with GSM networks in Mexico. This is because it is a model for Europe only; and uses the GSM (2G) 850/900/1800/1900 or "EDGE" and for 3G and HSDPA (H+) networks using 900/2100.

In Mexico the companies use other frequencies for the 3G:

Telcel 3G: 850 mhz
All others (Iusacell, Movistar, etc): 3G: 1900 mhz

Nobody in Mexico using 3G in 900 or 1200 MHz, so your phone only works in 2G, there is no way to operate 3G as it is at the hardware level.

Interestingly, the LTE frequency Telcel 2100 MHz works the same as "H+" of the Ubuntu Phone not assume anything but maybe (and just maybe) worth trying. :)

Comment: and you could give me the APN Iusacell LTE and Telcel LTE?

Comment: Take a look to this page: http://www.xatakandroid.com.mx/web-movil/coleccion-de-apns-de-redes-mexicanas